# Bash Script: Difference between %% and //

Tags: regex, string, bash

To remove all characters after a specific string in bash, I found out that there are two ways of doing it, either using the // or %%.

For example, if I want to rename files that have the format "This is the 505 file of a total of 83018 files". I can rename them by removing everything after the "of" string so that it is only named "This is the 505 file" using these 2 ways.

```
newfilename=${filename//of*}
```

and

```
newfilename=${filename%%of*}
```

Both of these when run, removes all characters after the "of" string.

I am wondering whats the difference between using %% and // when removing parts of a string and if there are cases when I should be using one over the other.

Thanks

Comment: `man bash` is your best bet

Comment: `man bash` is never your best bet.

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin: Why do you say that? `info bash` is easier to navigate, but the man page contains all the same information.

Comment: To elaborate more on @anubhava comment - `man bash | less +/Parameter\ Expansion` will take you to the relevant section. It is indeed your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

They are two different functions

```
${string//find/replace}

${string%%pattern}
```

e.g.

```
$ var="here of there of"; echo ${var//of}
here there
```

if you don't provide replacement string, it's a simple delete

```
$ var="here of there of"; echo ${var%%of}
here of there
```

this takes the longest substring matching the pattern